# Hosting an Express server in React Native

Tags: react-native, express, socket.io

I'm trying to build a real-time multi-player game using React Native, basically I want to make one of the phones as my server and the other ones as clients which are connected to the server.
this is my Express server:

**server.js**

```
let app = require('express')();
let port = 3000;
let server = require('http').createServer(app)
let io = require ('socket.io')(server)


module.exports = startServer = () => {
    io.on("connection", () => {
        console.log("someone has connected");
    })

    server.listen(port, () => {console.log("server is running at " + port)})
}
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
  ScrollView,
  View,
  TextInput,
  Text,
  StatusBar
} from "react-native";
let startServer = require('./server')


class App extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    startServer();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{justifyContent: 'center', alignContent: 'center', flex: 1}}>
        <TextInput style={{borderBottomWidth: 1}}/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});

export default App;
```

I use `startServer` in `componentDidMount`to start the server (just like how we do it with `node server.js`).

**client.js**

```
let io = require('socket.io-client');
let port = 3000

start = () => {
    socket = io(someIP + ":" + port);
}
```

So there are a few questions:
**1-** Is my general approach to implementing this rational and suitable?
**2-** React Native is unable to resolve module `http`, what's the alternative for creating a server in React Native?
**3-** What's the ip of the server that I must connect to in client.js? (should all devices be necessarily connected to the same internet network?)

Answer (score 1):

1. Personally don't think it's a good design choice to let a phone host a server for a game. Incredible amount of latency and lag will be introduced as a result of unstable network. If you are on a network, why not just call to an external server with socketio.
2. This is pretty niche. A little search I found "React Native does not implement node apis, this is why you cannot use the http module." from janicduplessis on react-natives github page. I did find a package react-native-http-bridge, but I think it doesn't support socketio. The funny part is I have looked into running a server on a phone before, and there are some native packages that do this for you (I think it was using WebSocket to host a POS system on a android pad). But the whole thing feels kind of like a hack.
3. I'd imagine 10.0.2.2:port for android. Idk about IOS. and you have to connect other people's phones to your local IP address like 192.168.1.06:port. It should say in your phone's network settings. Sometimes you have to connect to your own phone using that local IP address too. Not really sure unless I try.

Comment: They are not going to send information every frame, they are just going to send information (like a JSON) at the end of each round, so reasonable delay is not a problem. I'm looking for a solution which doesn't need internet, I think WIFI Hotspot can be a solution for my use case but I don't know how honestly.

Comment: Hey @mahdi, I am trying to do something similar. How did you solve it?